# CSS: "right" property refuse to apply?

Tags: css, position

This is driving me crazy!

I have two divs, right after the body tag. They are both absolute positioned and sized. They both have the same "left" property, but i later declare the "right" property for the second div (so "left" should be ignored!).

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="previousPageButton"></div>
<div class="nextPageButton"></div>
```

And the CSS: (There's more code to it but it's commented out so it's irrelevant.)

```
.previousPageButton, .nextPageButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 500px;;
    width: 100px;
    background: transparent url(../images/buttons/arrow_previousPage.png) no-repeat center center;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .1;
}

.nextPageButton {
    top: 0px; right: 150px;
    background: transparent url(../images/buttons/arrow_nextPage.png) no-repeat center center;
}
```

As you can see, BELOW the first CSS where i declare the "left", i have another block of CSS where i specifically declare the "right" property for .nextPageButton. Body is relatively positioned, as usual, so it should work! Do i need to "unset" the "left" property before declaring the "right" property? Is that even possible?

I know i could rip the "left" property out of the first codeblock, and then assign each div it's own left/right property.. but this should still work!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Using jsfiddle and firebug, only removing the left:property seems to work : http://jsfiddle.net/sCgsF/1/

Comment: Typo: height: 500px;;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`left` and `right` are not mutually exclusive.

An element can have both the `left` and `right` properties set, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtSSF/).

If you want to "remove"/"reset" `left`, then you should apply `left: auto`.

You can lookup the "inital value" of properties, for example [here's `left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/left).

Comment: I have the same problem with the "bottom" attribute now, kind of. jsfiddle.net/sCgsF/2/ that's the CSS for the footer, i haven't declared anything else for it. And for some reason it's just blank, nothing at all! Any ideas? I tried setting top to auto but it shouldn't matter now cause i've never set the top attribute at all on that element. If i set the bottom atribute to something negative, it shows up from the top of the page, just as if the body had 0 height. Ideas?

Comment: Is this it: http://jsfiddle.net/sCgsF/3/ ? If not, I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: Nope. I was saying the fiddle i posted works on jsfiddle, but not on my site (using the exact same CSS). It acts as if the body had no height, because if i set the bottom attribute to something negative, it works. I just managed to fix it though, i was right, the body had no height, and that was caused by me setting the position to relative before. I just removed it and now it's working great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see. `position: relative` would screw that up. I'm glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 3):

There is some inheritance that is causing a conflict. Add `left: auto;` to the `.nextPageButton` class to prevent.