# Right positioning refusing to work

Tags: html, css, sass

At the moment I'm working on a feature for my site where three circles transition into a new configuration at 900px. I have the circles working and they are all responsive which is good.

My plan is at 900px each circle will transform to a new configuration.

The blue circle `circle2` will be on the **left**, the magenta circle `circle1` will be on the **right** and the yellow circle `circle3` will be directly **underneath** and **centered** between `circle1` and `circle2`. I'm able to achieve transitioning `circle1` and `circle2` to the `left` and `circle3` to the `bottom`.

The issue I'm having is when I attempt to `transition` `circle3` to the `right` to center up with `circle1` and `circle2` and no matter what I do `circle3` will **not move to the right**. This may be because I have `relative` positioning set on `circle1` which I am `extending` to all the other circles with scss.

I think my issue has something to do with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940123/css-right-property-refuse-to-apply) on right positioning refusing to apply.

Can someone please explain to me why the `right` positioning property is refusing to work??

Please check out my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/LVdYQa?editors=110)

```
@mixin transitions {
  transition: top .5s linear, bottom .5s linear, left .5s linear, right .5s linear;
}

.circles {
   display: flex;
   justify-content:center;
}
 .circle1 {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content:center;
    border-radius:50%;
    padding-bottom:30%;
    height:0;
    width: 30%;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:magenta;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    @include transitions;

  #projects{
    line-height:1;
    margin-top:-0.5em;
    padding-top:50%;
    color:#fff;
   }
 }
```

Circles 2 and 3 that are being extended from `1`

```
.circle2{
  @extend .circle1;
  background-color:blue;
  #about{
    @extend #projects;    
  }
}
.circle3{
  @extend .circle1;
  background-color:gold;
  #contact{
    @extend #projects;
  }
}
```

Media Query set to 900px

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .circle3 {
    right: 100px;
    top: 200px;
  }

  .circle2 {
    left: 350px;
  }

  .circle1, .circle2, .circle3 {
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I will add code but I can't stand the re formatting I haft to do once it is added

Comment: @Daedalus code is all in now.

Comment: I've deleted my prior comments as they are now no longer relevant.

Comment: @Daedalus sure! Do you know why right positioning is not working?

Comment: I tried to figure out the css for your question, but I unfortunately can't; its a bit above me I'm afraid.  I'll vote up your question, though if I was doing this I wouldn't do it only with css.

Comment: @Daedalus scss is css it's just a DRY way to write css as in less repeating! You should look into learning scss. It's not hard to make the adjustment and it will save you lots of time http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Good try on trying to understand my question :)

Comment: To be clear, I know what sass is, I just don't know enough of the bare css itself to figure out how to answer this question.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation problem, ONLY post the compiled CSS.  Installing additional software should not be necessary if it is irrelevant to the question..

Answer (score 1):

It seems your @extended calls are being respected all the way into your breakpoints, meaning that all of the styles being applied to circle1 are being applied to circle 2 and circle 3.

That coupled with circle1 styles being the last to be defined at the breakpoint causes it to override the positioning of the other two. You can fix this by simply placing your .circle1 styles above your other two inside your breakpoint.

```
@media (max-width:900px){
  .circle1{
    left:100px;
  }
  .circle3{
    right:100px;
    top:200px;
  }

  .circle2{
    left:350px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good recognition. However I still was not able to achieve right positioning...I found a way around it tho by going `left:-250px;` altho this messes up my entire layout..I need to make my `circles` container contain my circles so they don't go wondering around the page. Looking to achieve this effect with the circles https://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/