# Position elements both left and right

Tags: css

Is there something about CSS that doesn't allow you to specify **both top and bottom or left and right values**?

Take [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/hjukc03c/):

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.first {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  right: 50px;
}
.second {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Try removing `right: 50px` and the position will remain the same. What's going on?

Comment: Relative positioning moves an element in regard to its default position. Using left _and_ right makes little sense in that scenario.

Comment: This doesn't work also for position: absolute and position: fixed. The browser does not react if you apply both left/right or top/bottom to either positioning property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: "right" property refuse to apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940123/css-right-property-refuse-to-apply)

Comment: Using BOTH left and right is usually only done with absolute positioning to set the width based on the parent container like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hjukc03c/7/

With relative positioning, it doesn't make sense to set both. You must use one or the other.

Comment: @kthornbloom See http://jsfiddle.net/ooepwogc/ if you remove position: right from .first nothing will happen. So this same thing happens for absolute positioning too. What's going on?

Comment: @daremkd That jsfiddle is still using relative positioning. Try removing left or right from this one: http://jsfiddle.net/hjukc03c/7/

Comment: @kthornbloom my bad I forgot to click 'update'. I meant this: http://jsfiddle.net/b7f38met/

Comment: Like others have mentioned, it's because you have a width set. Using both left & right means the box will get stretched (rather than moved) to the points you've specified on each side. However, if you set a width it can't get stretched.

Answer (score 8):

In your example, the element has a fixed width to 100px and you are specifying both `left` and `right` properties. On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right), you can read (emphasis mine) :

> When both the right CSS property and the left CSS property are
>   defined, the position of the element is overspecified. In that case,
>   **the left value has precedence** when the container is left-to-right
>   (that is that the right computed value is set to -left)[...]

So in your example the right value is ignored. For the [bottom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom), the same rule applies as the element's height is fixed.

*Note that this rule only applies for non static positioning*

Comment: Is it the same thing for top/bottom?

Comment: @daremkd yes if your element has a fixed height.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `left`/`right` and `top`/`bottom`, but if `width`/`height` is also present, their value **take precedence**, which makes some sense, as how can it be both at a certain `right`/`bottom` position and have a certain `width`/`height`.

This sample shows how it behaves.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.first, .second {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.second {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
}
.third {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/right):

> When both the right CSS property and the left CSS property are
>   defined, the position of the element is overspecified. In that case,
>   the left value has precedence when the container is left-to-right
>   (that is that the right computed value is set to -left), and the right
>   value has precedence when the container is right-to-left (that is that
>   the left computed value is set to -right).